# Maven Deployment on Multiple Containers

Tags: maven-2, junit, glassfish

I would like to know how I define multiple containers in Maven, one for development and debugging and one for production. For instance:

1. Embedded Glassfish with JUnit dependencies
2. Deploying on Glassfish Server with no tests (no auto deploy is required, I just make a manual copy to the domain).

So when I shall run the JUnit tests, I would do something like:

```
mvn test -P junit
```

And for build a package to deploy

```
mvn package -P webapp
```

I am writing example with the -P switch, since I have come up with this pom.xml so far:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>se.while</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>junit</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>4.8.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>               
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>webapp</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
            <!-- use this for javax.persistence <snapshots> <enabled>true</enabled></snapshots> -->
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I have now 2 problems (at least):

1. The tests seems to working with the "mvn test -P junit" but when I
   do "mvn package -P webapp" Maven seems to run the tests again (with
   no container I assume nor the junit dependency).
2. The Eclipse IDE lint checker does indicate errors in source code
   depending on activated profile. For instance, if I active the webapp
   profile, all the test classes will be error marked.

Can you please guide me?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to   this

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>${skip.junit.tests}</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

to **webapp** profile add

```
<properties>
   <skip.junit.tests>true</skip.junit.tests>
</properties>
```

to **junit** profile add

```
<properties>
   <skip.junit.tests>false</skip.junit.tests>
</properties>
```

Comment: You saved my next weekend! =) Thank you very much!